# Unable to open a new window in JavaFX

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

when i put the method "openPlanes" in button the option "onAction".
This show many errors.
But if I remove the "openPlanes" his open normal.

```
@FXML
    private void openPlanes() {
        openStage("view/Cadastro.fxml");
    }

private void openStage(String fxml) {
        try {
            Stage currentStage = (Stage) PLANE.getScene().getWindow();
            Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(fxml));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            Stage stage = new Stage(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
            currentStage.hide();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(mainController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
```

[image]

Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: No controller specified.
file:/C:/Users/diego/Documents/NetBeansProjects/Automekanik/DGDSoft/dist/run708547813/DGD%20Soft.jar!/dgdsoft/view/MainDGD.fxml:23

```
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2597)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.access$100(FXMLLoader.java:103)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.getControllerMethodHandle(FXMLLoader.java:557)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processEventHandlerAttributes(FXMLLoader.java:599)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:770)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:2823)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2532)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
at dgdsoft.DGDSoft.start(DGDSoft.java:19)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
... 1 more
```

Exception running application dgdsoft.DGDSoft
Java Result: 1

Comment: What are the errors? What is `openStage(...)`?

Comment: I was analyzing this guy's application
GitHub - https://github.com/mlayah/bookingFX/tree/master/src/bookingfx
YouTube - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ooT0Ueyngeo

I made some equal parts to learn more, I tried to modify some.
Now I was trying to call a second window but I did not understand this error and neither this code

Comment: "No controller specified" means you haven't specified the controller class in your FXML file.

Comment: hi, can you post your DGDSoft code to us or at least the start method?

Comment: @yab The problem is in the FXML file.

Answer (score 0):

At first make sure the fxml resource you are trying to load is in the directory you expect it to be. If it is in the appropriate directory then open the fxml file and search for the string **fx:controller**. 
Make sure the controller is inside the stated package.

If you don't find the string fx:controller in the fxml file then you need to do it programatically as:

```
 private Scene getScene(String fxmlPath, ControllerClass controller) {
        FXMLLoader loader;
        Parent parent;
        Scene scene;
        try {
            //not FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(fxmlPath)
            loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(fxmlPath));
            loader.setController(controller);
            parent = loader.load();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        scene = new Scene(parent);

        return scene;

    }
```

Lastly,  submit the fxml file and code.